# How to take only data from every 5 minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have data set of power consumption in a household for every minute. I wanted to take only data from every 5 minutes how can I do so?

Here is the table example:

[image: Data]

I have tried to use filter, but it doesn't seem to work. There are hundreds of thousands of data.

Comment: You could add a new column =MOD(MINUTE(A1),5)=0 which will return TRUE when the time is a multiple of 5 minutes. Then filter by that column?

Comment: @James solution should work unless you want a variable start time for the 5 minute increments. IE start at 43 minutes etc

Comment: That can easily be adjusted. For example `=MOD(MINUTE(A1+(1/24/60)),5)=0` will match 11:04, 11:09, 11:14 and so on

Comment: i wanted to keep only from minute 0-5-10... and so on

Comment: I tried seperating the date and time as well into new columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the date and time in column A, enter the formula:

```
=MOD(MINUTE(A1), 5) = 0
```

This will return `TRUE` for all times which are a multiple of 5 minutes (e.g. 23:00, 23:05), and `FALSE` for all other times.

You can then fill this formula to the whole column, and filter it to show only `TRUE` values.

Comment: This is what Im looking for thanks. I tried to filter it out and delete the selected row, but that option is not showing up do u know why'